# Get section length in linker script

Tags: assembly, ld, powerpc

I have a makefile which compiles modules written in assembler into a binary file to be loaded by another software. The interesting part of the makefile looks like this:

```
$(BUILD_ALL)/mod.elf.ld.inc:
    $(LOG)
    $Qecho "#define MOD(id, addr, ...) . = ALIGN(4); .rodata.id : { id ## _start = .; *(.text.id); id ## _size = ABSOLUTE(. - id ## _start); }" > $@
    ...

$(BUILD_ALL)/mod.data.o.inc:
    $(LOG)
    $Qecho "#define MOD(id, addr, ...) .int addr; .int id ## _start; .int id ## _size; .int 0; " > $@
    ...

$(BUILD_ALL)/mod.text.elf.ld.inc:
    $(LOG)
    $Qecho "#define MOD(id, addr, ...) .text.id addr : { *(.text.id); } " > $@
    ...

$(BUILD_ALL)/mod.text.o.inc:
    $(LOG)
    $Qecho "#define MOD(id, addr, ...) .section .text.id; __VA_ARGS__" > $@
    ...
```

What this does is it lets me define a module looking like this:

```
MOD(unique-id, 0x80001234, 
    li r3, 0; 
    li r4, 0; 
    ...
)
```

This then places the actual code inside the text section of the ELF file (see rule for mod.text.o.inc), will tell the linker to load it to the address I entered (rule for mod.text.elf.ld.inc), add loading address, size, file address to the data section of the ELF (mod.data.o.inc), and mod.elf.ld.inc is responsible to determine the size of the code.

The output for the Data section basically looks like this:

```
.int 0x80001234
 .int unique-id_start
 .int unique-id_size
 .int 0

.int 0x80003864
 .int mod1_start
 .int mod1_size
 .int 0

.int 0x80003ea4
 .int mod2_start
 .int mod2_size
 .int 0
```

I am now trying to modify this "build environment" so I have another command "IMOD" which I can use to "set" a destination address and make the  compiler place any other "DMOD" assignments not at an address I need to enter (like 0x80001234 in my example), but automatically at the end.

I tried copying MOD to IMOD and DMOD like this:

```
$(BUILD_ALL)/mod.elf.ld.inc:
    $(LOG)
    $Qecho "#define MOD(id, addr, ...) . = ALIGN(4); .rodata.id : { id ## _start = .; *(.text.id); id ## _size = ABSOLUTE(. - id ## _start); }" > $@
    $Qecho "#define IMOD(id, addr, ...) . = ALIGN(4); .rodata.id : { id ## _start = .; *(.text.id); id ## _size = ABSOLUTE(. - id ## _start); last_size = addr + SIZEOF(.rodata.id); }" >> $@
    $Qecho "#define DMOD(id, ...) . = ALIGN(4); .rodata.id : { id ## _start = .; *(.text.id); id ## _size = ABSOLUTE(. - id ## _start); last_size = last_size + SIZEOF(.rodata.id); }" >> $@
    ...
```

so that it adds the section size to a counter, and then added this:

```
$(BUILD_ALL)/mod.data.o.inc:
    $(LOG)
    $Qecho "#define MOD(id, addr, ...) .int addr; .int id ## _start; .int id ## _size; .int 0; " > $@
    $Qecho "#define IMOD(id, addr, ...) .int addr; .int id ## _start; .int id ## _size; .int 0; " > $@
    $Qecho "#define DMOD(id, ...) .int last_size; .int id ## _start; .int id ## _size; .int 0; " > $@
    ...
```

However, the resulting section (generated from mod.data.o.inc) does not have increasing addresses for ".int last_size", not even a wrong address, but the (section) length of the whole ELF Data section - not just the one section I want it to.

Basically, if I call IMOD(test, 0x80001000, nop;) and then DMOD(test2, nop;), I want the address 0x80001004 written to the ELF data section. Instead, the code I (tried to) write writes the ELF data section length instead.

I am sorry if my explanation is shit - English is not my mother tongue, the build environment hasn't been written by me (so I don't exactly know what everything does) and I don't have much experience with how a linker works.

I can give [a link to the build environment / code](https://github.com/Chadderz121/wii-ct-code/blob/master/bad1/bad1Data/mod/makefile.mk) but that is very specific to that system / software so I don't know if this is useful.

Comment: no two linkers are expected to be compatible in anywa, are you talking about gnu's linker ld?

Comment: Sorry I forgot that. Yes, I am using GNU ld powerpc-eabi-ld 2.27.

Comment: It might not help you much because you seem to be working with an existing setup, but I would just use existing functionality of `objcopy` to embed files. I avoid linker scripts if at all possible.

Comment: If I had written all that from scratch / would write that from scratch, I wouldn't have used these, too. But I'd like to use the existing setup, if possible.

Comment: I could write a small C tool going through the compiled binary file, and adding up the section lengths manually and repair the offsets (and this is what I'll probably do if I won't find a solution to this problem), but this seems very messy and not a clean solution ...